# opening vim with custom location for .vimrc

Tags: vim, bashrc

I have my .vimrc file in a custom location (~/dotfiles/vim/.vimrc).
When I type i:

```
vim 'filename'
```

I would like to execute the command:

```
vim -u ~/dotfiles/vim/.vimrc 'filename'
```

I put this function in my .bashrc:

```
function vim() {
    vim -u  ~/dotfiles/vim/.vimrc $1
}
```

However, I don't see the changes from my .vimrc, pretty sure the standard vim is opened.

Comment: did you do a `source .bashrc` after adding the function? Or close and re-open the file again?

Comment: No, but I tried it now. It still does not work.

Comment: But the syntax is correct?

Comment: Could you change the function name to be slightly different then actual `vim` name something like `vimf`? and open the file as `vimf <filename>`

Comment: You should probably use `command vim` to avoid recursion in your function.

Comment: I tried a different filename and he did not find the command

Comment: I restarted my notebook and now it is working!
thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd recommend using the full path to vim in your function.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to use bash for this, it can be accomplished through a symlink. It would be a file reference from the default location to your custom location.

```
ln -s ~/dotfiles/vim/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

This method will still allow you maintain everything in `~/dotfiles`, editing such as `vim ~/.vimrc` will be the same as `vim ~/dotfiles/vim/.vimrc`.